# Importing winappdbg gives ModuleNotFoundError for breakpoint in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Whenever I try to just import winappdbg it gives me an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'breakpoint'`. So, I tried installing breakpoint and that gives me another error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` and I've installed `configparser` several times and still get the error. (Can't find capital ConfigParser) I'm using Windows 10/PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3/python 3.6.3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more quickly if you [edit] your question to show an example code snippet that causes the error. See [mcve] for some tips on how to create a good code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinAppDbg is only for Python 2.x, it does not work on Python 3.x. Honestly, I had no idea it would even let you import it.

All those import errors are happening not because of missing dependencies (also, no idea there were similarly named modules in pip), they are submodules of WinAppDbg itself. Since Python 3 has a different syntax to specify those, it tries to load them as external modules instead. I suppose you could fix that in the sources by prepending a dot before every submodule import, but I'm guessing more stuff would break down the road (string handling for example is radically different and that would affect the ctypes layer).

TL;DR: use Python 2.x.